# Serilog DI with custome properties in a common way

Tags: api, logging, grpc, serilog

Generally, i have 2 questions, i am unable to post custom properties on the API level and microservice level. I always got empty values in the database

I want these properties to be added to the log as custom properties (they are present in db as columns

```
public interface IRequestContext
{
    public Guid RequestId { get; }

    public long? UserId { get; }

    public long? CustomerId { get; }

    public long HostId { get; }
}
```

I add Serilog like this in API and microservice (i use ILogger, not static one, because want to mock in unit-tests)

```
public static void AddSerilog(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<ILogger>(s => new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.With(new UtcTimestampEnricher())
        .CreateLogger());
}
```

I can post in gRPC message interceptor like this, and that's fine

```
try
{
    return await continuation(request, context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
_logger.ForContext(SerilogConstants.CustomColumns.REQUESTCONTEXT_HOSTID, _requestContext.HostId)                    .ForContext(SerilogConstants.CustomColumns.REQUESTCONTEXT_USERID, _requestContext.UserId)
                    .ForContext(SerilogConstants.CustomColumns.REQUESTCONTEXT_CUSTOMERID, _requestContext.CustomerId)
                    .ForContext(SerilogConstants.CustomColumns.REQUESTCONTEXT_REQUESTID, _requestContext.RequestId)
                    .ForContext(SerilogConstants.CustomColumns.ERROR_STACKTRACE, ex.StackTrace)
                    .ForContext(SerilogConstants.CustomColumns.LOGS_SOURCE_TYPE, (int)LogsSourceType.MicroserviceExceptionHandling)
                    .Error(ex, ex.Message);
}
```

I can post in exception handling middleware in API in the similar way, and it also works fine

But what if i want just write single line in the API or microservice, like this

```
 _logger.Information("DDDD");
```

Together with this log i want all those _requestContext properties automatically to be saved to database.

I tried to create new custom enrichter, but it cannot resolve IRequestContext
I tried using PushProperty in API in the new another middleware, but again empty values saved to db.

I'm lost now what to add, please advice